# Cannot create a Virtual Network with Resource Manager (Forever Loading...)

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I want to join a Cloud Service to a Virtual Network so I'm trying to create my VNet first.  I can create a "Classic" VNet (through portal.azure.com) without any problems but the Cloud Service cannot find that network during deployment.  If I choose "Resource Manager" for the VNet creation process, then the panel for the VNet settings flies out but everything is greyed out and Subscription and Location just read "Loading...." with a padlock next to them.

I've tried re-booting the machine, different browsers, and different PCs.  No luck.  What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

-Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed the same problem a few days ago and I reported it to a Microsoft employee. He told me it was going to be fixed soon.

This morning I checked again and I could create a VNET with Resource Manager.

Comment: Thanks, figures just bad timing on my part. :)

Answer (score 0):

resources created by RM are not exposed to classic portal, vise versa.

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't really my question.  I cannot create using the RM method at all.  The page never loads fully.